# Why does this return the same timestamp every time unless I re-build and run the app?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsdate, unix-timestamp

My app allows users to add new items to their inventory. Every time an item is added, one of the properties that get associated with that item is the timestamp of when it was added. To get that timestamp, I use the following code:

```
float timestamp = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
```

If I add multiple items during one session of using the app (i.e., I just build & run it once, but go through the add process multiple times), the timestamp always comes out the same. Once I build and run the app again, however, the timestamp changes. But then it doesn't change again until I re-build & run.

I know it's not a problem of storing the item data, because if I log the `timestamp` variable (rather than just looking at the item's timestamp property), I see this failure to change.

Why isn't it changing?

In case it matters, I'm running this on the iPhone simulator.

Comment: Have you tried the C-function `time(NULL)`? Is it giving errors, too?

Comment: @user523234 - according to what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`-[NSDate timeIntervalSince1970]` return a `NSTimeInterval` not a `float`.

Comment: Thanks. I see that NSTimeInterval is a typedef for double, not float. That was my real mistake.